# Как через switch делать арифметические сравнения?

Tags: javascript

Например, у меня на выходе:

```js
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

- дает случайное число от 0 до 100.

Мне нужно как-то донести до switch чтобы он перебирал числа, чтобы он выводил текст без цифр, а текстом что в массиве было. Код такой сейчс:

```js
switch (randomNum) {
    case randomNum > 69:
        console.log('randomNum больше 69');
        break;
    case randomNum < 14:
        console.log('randomNum меньше 14');
        break;
default: console.log('randomNum меньше 69 и больше 14')
break;
}
```

Но он почему-то неправильный, и всегда выводит default.
Есть еще вариант создать другие массивы с диапазоном цифр внутри, но итог тот же

Вообще switch умеет сравнивать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `switch (true) { case randomNumber > 50: ...`

Comment: А, это опечатка просто) сюда когда писал программа немного другая была, но суть та же

Comment: Собственно, с javascript я не знаком, но обычно в ветках ```case``` нельзя ставить условие. Там указывается выражение, на равенство с которым проверяется выражение, указанное в ```switch```. Таким образом, вы проверяете не то, что ```randomNumber > 50```, а что ```randomNumber ==(randomNumber > 50) ```. Допускаю, что могу быть не прав, и в JS ```switch/case``` работает иначе. А вообще - загляните [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: да вот прочитал другие ответы на сайте, кажется кейс не сравнивает больше/меньше, а правда или ложь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще, case сравнивает на соответствие правда/ложь (при том строгое сравнение). Но есть нестандартное поведение, которым можно добиться сравнение больше/меньше. Просто поставить true в switch, [switch - Второй способ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```js
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
switch (true) {
  case randomNum > 69:
    console.log(`${randomNum} больше 69`);
    break;
  case randomNum < 14:
    console.log(`${randomNum} меньше 14`);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`${randomNum} не больше 69 и не меньше 14`);
}
```

Comment: а это вообще законно? или просто баг javascript?

Comment: @KoVadim, а что не так? Есть проверяемое значение, есть значения для вариантов - все ок :)

Comment: как по мне, это больше баг js. В других ЯП (большинстве) нет такой возможности

Comment: я понимаю, как это работает. Мне интересно это официальная фича-баг, или просто случайно в некоторых браузерах работает. Но мне больше нравится паскаль подход. жаль его почти никуда не подвезли

Comment: @KoVadim, ну в доке нет ограничений. Официальная фича-баг. Т.е. это полноценная возможность в языке

Comment: Хз из-за чего нормальная/естественная гибкость (свойственная динамическим интерпретируемым языкам) тут воспринимается багом... В компилируемых языках, отсутствие такой возможности обусловлено в первую очередь их "врожденной" ограниченностью (а именно - требованием к значениям case быть константными, что следует из самого принципа компиляции: допуск неконстант возможен, но автоматически означает весьма сильное усложнение выходных инструкций, чего стараются избегать). Но интерпретируемые языки имеют все возможности для поддержки неконстантных кейсов - так почему же им не следует быть?

Comment: @yar85, да, вы правы. Но, наверное , данный вопрос, относится к холиварным. Лично я придерживаюсь мнения, чтобы фундаментальные конструкции ЯП были максимально похожими (на сколько это возможно).  И как по мне, switch как бы сам за себя говорит, что тут константа. В других случаях чем плох if-elseif-else ...

Comment: @yar85, даже само описание switch, как бы противоречит этому подходу. Switch "сравнивает выражение со случаями". И тут раз - мы вместо выражения ставим true - и уже "НЕ сравниваем выражение со случаями". Зачем это?

Comment: _«И тут раз - мы вместо выражения ставим true - и уже "НЕ сравниваем выражение со случаями".»_ - почему же не сравниваем, когда это по факту является сравнением вычисленных значений с `true`? Разве "смена местами" операндов логического выражения `something == true` что-то концептуально меняет? :) Согласен, это непривычная форма записи, но она вполне логична и результат дает ожидаемый (имхо), поэтому я не понимаю почему ее называют багом.

Comment: да ,согласен слово "баг" может и не совсем корректное в данном случае. Но, как вы сказали  "смена местами - концептуально не меняет" - но как по мне, то меняет -  меняет логику "построения" кода, и для меня она не совсем логична. Да и зачем это нужно, если есть нормальный синтаксис для этого?